# Where is the key and IV storage location in .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have asp.net MVC 5 project and encrypt user sensitive information and store in database ,when i show data for user get information from database and decrypted (encrypt / decrypt in mvc project and store data encrypted in database).

I use `AesCryptography` for encrypt/descrypt data . i have Key and IV ,Where is the key and IV storage location?

must save in webconfig or create a separate table in database with Key and Iv columns or add Key/IV columns to user table.

is a good idea create a key and Iv for each row data ?

Comment: Option 1: Environment variable.  Option 2: Machine.config.  Option 3: Database.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You supposed to store Key in web.config. Use `appSettings` as the simplest way, it is totally fine.

```
  <appSettings>
      <add key="DataEnryptionKey" value="allyourbase"/>
  </appSettings>
```

WIKI:

> An initialization vector has different security requirements than a
>   key, so the IV usually does not need to be secret. However, in most
>   cases, it is important that an initialization vector is never reused
>   under the same key.

The whole point of IV is to be different for every encryption operation. So when you encrypt "123" two times you will not get the same encrypted output. See wiki.

So it is not ok to store IV in web.config. Generic approach - to store IV as a first block of cipher.

**Simple way**

Use `MachineKey.Protect` / `MachineKey.Unprotect` methods
They already do stuff in a secure way.

You only will have to generate keys using IIS or other tool.

---

[image]

---

[image]